# Windows Phone 8.1 RadioButton IsChecked not work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have *StackPanel* with two radio button. IsChecked not work/checke in both on screen.

```js
<RadioButton Name="SettingsRB128" BorderBrush="Aqua" IsChecked="{Binding SettingsRB128}"></RadioButton>
<RadioButton Name="SettingsRB64" BorderBrush="Aqua" IsChecked="True">
```

But in code, value is correct

```c#
Debug.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", SettingsRB128.IsChecked, SettingsRB64.IsChecked)
```

If remove

```js
BorderBrush="Aqua"
```

RadioButton not visible on screen.

Comment: When you need a BorderBrush to see the box, the mark may also have the wrong colour. Try a contrasting background colour.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

In Designer
1. select radiobutton
2. Right mouse "Edit template" - "Edit Copy" - "Ok"

change

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush" Color="Magenta"/>
```

and

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="Checked">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```